# Why does EVP_PKEY_keygen() fail?

Tags: c++, openssl, diffie-hellman

From what I have gathered reading the OpenSSL wiki page, my code to generate a Diffie-Hellman key is correct.  But it fails on the last step -- EVP_PKEY_keygen().

Is there a way to get more detailed information besides pass/fail?  Perhaps even the reason it failed?

Comment: There's a standard mechanism for finding out the meaning of an error in OpenSSL.  I forget the spelling and magic incantation, but it is uniform and relatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get more detailed information out of OpenSSL errors.  It's minimal but generally helpful.

```
#include <openssl/err.h>

// Do this during construction or initialization
ERR_load_crypto_strings();

// Do this when an error occurs
unsigned long error = ERR_get_error();
cout << "Error code = " << error << std::endl;
cout << ERR_reason_error_string(error) << std::endl;

// Do this when shutting down
ERR_free_strings();
```